# What does lighter color mean in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorboard

I attached an image of my distributions on tensorboard. I can see some very light color in the graph. It looks very noisy. What is this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These curves indicate **percentile**, in which the light color curves are max (99 th percentile) and min (1 th percentile).
As the definition of percentile, a percentile is a number where a certain percentage of values are fall below that percentile value.
For example in the following figure, assume that we are talking about **steps 1000**, at the **93 th percentile line**, there were 93% of the values are below **0.200**

[image]

Why is (99th, 93th, 84th, 69th, 50th, 31th, 16th, 7th, 1th) but not other percentiles ? Because they were declared in the tensorboard README.md, [which is documented here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md).
Hope this helps !

Comment: Awesome! I see it is kind of histogram of percentage. This is really helpful.